# working with recursion in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

here is my code

```
   def printTriangleRecursive(width):
# Recursive implementation
 if width > 1:
    printTriangleRecursive(width - 1)
 print ("*" * width, end=" ")
```

Am suppose to get this using recursion

```
    * 
    * * 
   * * * 
   * * * * 
   * * * * *
```

but am getting a different staff

Answer (score 0):

By default, `print` will issue a newline after printing the text. But with

```
end=" "
```

you are overriding that behavior and telling it to print a space instead of a newline.

To fix, just delete that

```
def printTriangleRecursive(width):
    # Recursive implementation
    if width > 1:
        printTriangleRecursive(width - 1)
    print ("*" * width)
```